# In Scala, is the transitive rule of covariance missing?

Tags: scala, generics, covariance, higher-kinded-types

E.g.

```
  trait AA[+X[n], +Y] {

    def x: X[Y] // [Error]: covariant type Y occurs in invariant position in type => X[Y] of method x
  }
```

This appears to be the wrong message, as X[Y] can be easily proven to be covariant:

if Y1 >:> Y2, +X1[n] >:> +X2[n] for all n, then:

Y1 >:> Y2

(covariance of X2) => X2[Y1] >:> X2[Y2]

(X1[Y1] >:> X2[Y1]) => X1[Y1] >:> X2[Y2]

What may have caused this error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing one more `+`. Correct is

```
trait AA[+X[+n], +Y] {
  def x: X[Y]
}
```

Then the type `X` will be covariant (with respect to its type parameter `n`) and the position

```
  def x: X[...]
//         ^^^  <- this position
```

will be covariant and you'll be able to use covariant type parameter `Y` at this position.

On contrary, you declared invariant type `X` (w.r.t. `n`) and tried to use covariant type parameter `Y` at an invariant position.

There are different notions:

- covariant/contravariant/invariant type parameter (`+T`, `-T`, `T`)
- covariant/contravariant/invariant type, i.e. type constructor, with respect to its type parameter (`T1 <: T2 => A[T1] <: A[T2]`, `T1 <: T2 => A[T1] >: A[T2]`, or none of those)
- covariant/contravariant/invariant position according to the rules https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#variance-annotations

`+X[n]` is a covariant type parameter of `AA` but invariant type with respect to its type parameter `n`.

The following conclusion was incorrect:

> (covariance of X2) => X2[Y1] >:> X2[Y2]

Also correct would be to make `Y` invariant

```
trait AA[+X[n], Y] {
  def x: X[Y]
}
```

---

By the way, yesterday Oleg Nizhnikov ([@odomontois](https://stackoverflow.com/users/210905/odomontois)) had a training on variances (among other topics) https://youtu.be/l08tK1x89ho?t=7494 (starting from 2:04:54).

Comment: wow, can't believe I forgot it :)